# How can I dynamically retrieve data from a form?

Tags: javascript

In my code (HTML and JS), I have a form with two fields; field A and field B. I want to write the JS code that will get the data from field A and use it to set the default value for field B. Can someone help me do that?

Comment: what should be the logic flow? whatever user types in A should automatically appear in B?

Comment: add details about what you have tried till now.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter. What I type in A should be manipulated and the resulting value displayed in B. I want this to happen after I have just typed 5 characters in A; before typing the entire string in A. For demonstration I think it's fine if you show me how to display in B what I type in A in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decompose the problem into smaller pieces, there appear to be three components:

- Get value from Field A
- Set value of Field B
- Trigger the event

Let's start with the first one...

There are [lots of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563667/328193) to reference an element.  Let's assume for a moment that your element has an `id`:

```
<input type="text" id="fieldA" />
```

Given that, we can get its value:

```
var valueOfFieldA = document.getElementById('fieldA').value;
```

Now that we have the value, let's move on to the second component...

Similar to above, all we have to do is reference the element.  Once we have that, we can set its `.value` property just as easily as we can read it.  Let's assume another `id` in the markup:

```
<input type="text" id="fieldB" />
```

Given that, we can set its value:

```
document.getElementById('fieldB').value = valueOfFieldA;
```

Finally, we want to trigger this.  Should it be when a button is pressed?  When something else happens?  For now I'm going to assume it should be when the value of Field A changes, so let's attach the code to the event handler for the `change` event of Field A:

```
document.getElementById('fieldA').onchange = function () {
    var valueOfFieldA = document.getElementById('fieldA').value;
    document.getElementById('fieldB').value = valueOfFieldA;
};
```

Assuming that the elements exist at the time this code runs and that it's able to find them by their `id` properties, this final result should assign a function to the `change` event of Field A such that whenever its value changes the value is then set to Field B.

Comment: Thank you David. The solution above works but only when I hit somewhere after I have typed in A. Is there a way I can get B updated as I'm typing in A?

Comment: @user3035404: The `keypress` event should do the trick.  There are lots of other JavaScript events you can use as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events